What object am I referring to?
I am large, much much larger than anything else like me.
There are 25, some say 26, others like me.
The smallest is about 8000.
What am I?

If you think there are multiple possible answers, notify me and I will clarify.

Sorry but I think this is far too "you know it or you don't" to make an interesting riddle. (And I'm in the "immediately know it" camp)

You are

 the monster group, which is the largest sporadic group. There are 25/26 others, depending on if you count the Tits Group. The smallest group has order 7920 (Mathieu M11)

